# display all the ssh pids where the users are connected to in one line

Tags: linux, bash, command, output

How can I display all the ssh pids where the users are connected to in one line separated by comma ?

This command displays the output in multiple lines, I would like to have the output in one line.

```
ps aux | grep -i "ssh" | awk '{print $2}'
```

**from**

```
1325
3255
2323
5321
3252
```

**To**

```
1325, 3255, 2323, 5321, 3252
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `pgrep` to get the processes IDs directly:

```
$ pgrep ssh
1217
5305
```

This way, you avoid calling `ps aux` and parsing its output, which will always contain the `grep` itself.

To join them on a `,`-separated list, use `paste` on a `-s`erial mode:

```
$ pgrep ssh | paste -s -d,
1217,5305
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed utility in another pipe, so the command would be:

```
ps aux | grep -i "ssh" | awk '{print $2}' | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/, /};ba'
```

Where you are in fact replacing new lines (except the final one) by commas.

Comment: Something went wrong. Since I am quite newbie with sed and awk, the command seems to be incomplete. Could you please take a look and tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: Thank you ! Works like charm! silly me,I should have seen that '. Next time, I will :)

Comment: Note that doing `something | grep | awk | sed` is quite inefficient. It can be probably handled alone by `awk`.

Comment: As written on the previous answer, pgrep and paste are way more efficient. I just followed OP's code.

Comment: Thank you, all! I really appreciate your help